# How to add an ID to the table generated by a view?

Tags: views, 8

In a site I'm building with Drupal 8.5.3, I designed a view that displays the content of a custom content entity: Members (Adhérents in french).
This view (system name = members) displays a page (system name = page_1) that uses table format to output the data.
As expected, the generated html is something like:

```
<table class="views-table views-view-table cols-8 sticky-enabled">
    <thead>
        <tr>...</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd">...</tr>
        <tr class="even">...</tr>
        <tr class="odd">...</tr>
        <tr class="odd">...</tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need this table to have an id, i.e. `<table class="views-table views-view-table cols-8 sticky-enabled" id="ListOfMembers">`.

How can I do that using either standard Views UI or anything Drupal-like?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution:
I duplicated `views-view-table.html.twig` into `views-view-table--members--page_1.html.twig` and changed

```
<table{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
```

into

```
<table{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }} ID="ListOfMembers">
```

and the result is what I wanted:
[image]